# python mapping a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, iteration

The title is a little misleading, but relevant.

consider the following code:

```
def add_page_to_index(index, url, content):
    words = content.split()
    for word in words:
        add_to_index(index, word, url)
```

I would like to change the for loop into something akin to this:

```
[add_to_index(index, word, url) for word in words]
```

I am quite sure the above line does not actually work, and may horrify people, however, i think it gives the gist of what I am trying to achieve. I would ideally like to use the map() function here, but I am unable to see how I can use map() because neither of the args 'index' or 'url' will change(they are not sequences), only 'word in words' will provide a sequence for the function. My question then is, if it's possible, how might I employ the map function here. Also, with regards to my above line of (probably abhorrent) code, how might I make such a line work... I am guessing I could make it into a list comprehension if I assigned it to a name, but that wouldn't really make sense in this situation.

Comment: Without example input it is hard to say if it is relevant but signature of function is `add_page_to_index(index, url, content)` and you call it `add_to_index(index, word, url)` so if your naming is coherent you call the function with wrong argument order.

Comment: Why use `map` or a list comprehension to build a list that you are just going to discard? They aren't intended as one-line replacements for `for` loops.  Keep your code the way it is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line will actually work and have correct side effects, only the *intent* of the code will be wrong, since the list comprehension is generally used to transform a list, not apply a function to each element.

That is,

```
def add_page_to_index(index, url, content):
    [add_to_index(index, word, url) for word in content.split()]
```

is a valid reimplementation of what you have, however, it is not straightforward since the results of the comprehension isn't being used.

If you're trying to learn how to use the map function, the following is what you're probably looking for:

```
def add_page_to_index(index, url, content):
    words = content.split()
    map(lambda word: add_to_index(index, word, url), words)
```

However, if you're just ignoring the results, I'd go with  your original for loop. It's more clear that the task is imperative and not transformative.

Comment: So the list comprehension type line can actually work even when not assigned to a name? Also, the lambda solution looks like it certainly answers my question as to how to include the args that aren't sequences so thanks for that. The only reason I am after a one-liner solution really is I am challenging myself to minimize line count in some code, as an excercise, but I suppose that's probably pointless at the expense of clarity

Comment: Nothing needs to be assigned in Python to execute (that is, Python is not a lazy language). All statements in true branches are executed. Minimal code line count doesn't imply more clear code and can confuse the reader even further. For a good metric of how Pythonic code looks, look at Python's standard library.